# Не могу зайти на сайт ru.goddady

Tags: https

Переустановил систему.
Пробовал разные сайты, https - все работают.
А вот https://ru.godaddy.com/ не хочет почему-то. "Подключение к сайту не защищено"
Время нормальное стоит, куки удалял. Удалил  даже парочку последних обновлений win7.
С телефона захожу,все гуд.
Самое странное, что вроде только на godaddy не заходит, говорит сертификат истек.
Как такое может быть? И главное, как решить проблему, где копать?
Браузер chrome, internet explorer таже фингня.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]

Comment: Откройте консоль и выполните команду `nslookup ru.godaddy.com`. Какие адреса видите?

Comment: Добавил скрин запроса

Comment: Адреса верные, попробуйте открыть явным образом `https://ru,godaddy.com` - с `https` вначале. И пришлите скрин сообщения Вашего браузера. Попробуйте Internet Explorer - в нем как правило более понятно - если появится перечеркнутая иконка замка - кликните по ней. Что говорит? Проверьте, что у Вас в системе установлен корневой сертификат `Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority G2`

Comment: Добавил, пробовал установить все что есть у godaddy на сайте, там их много, потом попробовал удалить, думал может какойто старый остался, толку нет.

Comment: Только заметил, с godaddy есть ссылка на сайт каких-то сертификатов, так на него тоже по https не хочет заходить https://comodosslstore.com/

Comment: В свойствах сертификата переключитесь на вкладку путь сертификации. Там будет обозначен сертификат, который у Вас отсутствует - скорее всего корневой. Пришлите скрин

Comment: Добавил, а еще, не знаю будет ли эта информация полезной,  на https://comodosslstore.com chrome напрочь отказывается переходить, и пишет     Подключение не защищено
Злоумышленники могут пытаться похитить ваши данные с сайта comodosslstore.com (например, пароли, сообщения или номера банковских карт). Подробнее…
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91945/discussion-between-sergey-nudnov-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема с отсутствием в системе одного или более корневых сертификатов. Сложно сказать как такое могло случиться.

Выполните следующие шаги, чтобы решить проблему:

1. Откройте командную строку и запустите проверку системного диска: `chkdsk c: /f` Если понадобится, перезагрузите компьютер.
2. Проверьте состояние Вашего дискового накопителя на предмет сбойных секторов. Могу порекомендовать [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/download/#CrystalDiskInfo)
3. Если найдутся проблемы с диском - решайте их в первую очередь, перед выполнением остальных шагов.
4. Выполните проверку и восстановление системных файлов, запустив команду из командной строки `sfc /scannow` (может потребоваться установочный диск операционной системы). Это выполнить желательно, но не обязательно.
5. Если у Вас Windows Vista,7 or 8, то установите обновление [kb2813430](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2813430/an-update-is-available-that-enables-administrators-to-update-trusted-a). Когда откроете статью, линки для загрузки будут ближе к концу. Текст можете тоже почитать, но не обязательно. :)
6. Скачайте программу [`rootsupd.exe`](https://forum.kontur.ru/resource.ashx?a=6727) в каталог на диске, например **`c:\temp`** Ранее эта программа распространялась Microsoft для использования с Windows XP. Но после завершения срока поддержки XP, Microsoft убрала все ресурсы с их сайта. Поэтому нашел линку на одном из форумов.
7. Откройте командную строку **с правами администратора** (Пуск-Найти-cmd-кликнуть правой кнопкой на иконке и выбрать "Выполнить от администратора"). Выполните команды:

---

```
cd c:\temp
rootsupd.exe /C /T:c:\temp
certutil.exe -generateSSTFromWU -f roots.sst
updroots.exe roots.sst
```

Это позволит восстановить набор корневых сертификатов на Вашем компьютере.
Объяснение шагов:

- перейти в каталог со скачанной rootsupd;
- распаковать rootsupd
- скачать с Microsoft свежий список корневых сертификатов
- обновить корневые сертификаты в системе

---

8. Выполните обновление системы, используя Windows Update. Можете пропустить этот шаг, если вы отключили обновления по какой-либо причине. Но я бы рекомендовал обновления не отключать

Comment: certutil неизвестный аргумент -generateSSTFromWU

Comment: Добавил пункт по установке kb2813430

Comment: @СергейЧумаков, Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа